# How to validate a date in PHP when the format can vary

Tags: php, validation, date

I am working on a site and have to validate a date from a form. i am using jquery picker to select the date, however, the user can change the selection manually therefore i want to validate for any possible format (January, 1 2000, 1 jan 2000 etc).
I have looked around and am having trouble finding a solution. I am trying using strtottime to turn the date to a stamp and I am then using checkdate. The validation with strtotime works fine if i enter for instance January 40, 2000, however, if i enter a date that is below or equal to 31 with any month strtotime moves it to the following month, for instance, february 31, 2017 turns to March 3, 2017.
This is making the checkdate function useless as the date passed to it is always valid. is there a solution to this?

```
    $thisD = 'February 31, 2017';
if (strtotime($thisD) === false)
{
    echo "<BR>DATE FORMAT NOT VALID <BR>";
}
else
{
    echo "<BR>DATE FORMAT  VALID <BR>";
    $thisDStr = strtotime($thisD);
    echo "Original date was $thisD, date now is " . date('F, j Y',$thisDStr). ' -> ';

        if (checkdate(date('n',$thisDStr), date('j',$thisDStr), date('Y',$thisDStr)))
        {
            echo ' is valid <br>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo ' is NOT valid <br>';
        }
}//end else
```

Comment: The only good answer is to prevent the user from changing it manually.  The date picker will only allow valid dates and force a format.

Comment: Check the input against a few acceptable formats (`Y-m-d`, `m-d-Y`, `F, j, Y` etc) using regex, and extract the different matches (primarily day of month and year) and then compare that with what `date('d', $thisDStr)` and `date('Y', $thisDStr)` returns.  If the values don't match, then they manipulated the date in some way.  By checking the input against what a "valid" input to strtotime returns you can see if something changed.

Comment: Thank you, since it does not seem possible I will force a number of predefined formats and stick to it!